# How can one properly understand the fact that $e^x$ can be differentiated an infinite amount of times?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Simply put if I follow the rule derived by the simple proof denoting $e^x$ to be the derivative of $e^x$ then it follows that it should have an infinite number of derivatives. Is this a conceptual mistake ( on my part) or one deeper within the proof ?

Comment: There is no mistake, with your remark, a trivial induction gives you the existence and value of the n-th derivative for every n, and this imply that it's $C^\infty$

Comment: Yes.  $\frac{\operatorname d^n \mathsf e^x}{\operatorname d x\;^n} = \mathsf e^x$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$, so the sequence of non-zero derivatives is infinite. &nbsp; The function is in $\mathrm C^\infty$.

Comment: "differentiated" is the proper word, not "derived".

Comment: Think of it as an eigenvector of the differentiation operator corresponding to eigenvalue one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake, with your remark, a trivial induction gives you the existence and value of the n-th derivative for every n, and this imply that it's $C^\infty$ – Tryss [answered in comments]